# Working out price of product using math in PHP

Tags: php, math

If I have an integer value of **8.32** which represents the price of **100,000**, what **PHP** function would I use if I wanted to work out the price of **3,268,937**

So for every **100,000** it'd cost **8.32**, how could I work this out using a simple PHP function (if it exists) ?

```
$price = 8.32;
$total_product_value = 3268937; (this would be unique everytime)

$price * 10 * how many millions in the $total_product_value or something like this
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I've understood what you mean, I think you have only to divide the total 3,268,937 by 100,000 and then multiply it by 8.32...so:

```
$total_product_value=3268937*$price/100000;
```